# Convergence of the functional series and limit function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What is the range of convergence of this functional series?

Let M - the range of convergence of
$S(x)$=$\sum_{i=1}^\infty$ $\sqrt[n]{x}$ $e^{-nx}$

Is $S(x)$ continuous on M?
How to find the sum of a series?

I suppose that $M=[0, +\infty)$

Comment: Do you not think that $[0,\infty)$ is a closed and unbounded set?

Comment: If you obtained an answer, I'd suggest showing your work to see what might have went wrong. Also, "the answers say that M is closed and unlimited set", and your answer is such a set. What makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: Ok, I realized my mistake. Thank you. But how to find the sum of series?

Comment: Hint: Try using the geometric series.